# Firestore serverTimestamp

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to save the server timestamp in Firestore Database with this format: 1508805681? FieldValue.serverTimestamp() saves it as the exact date and ServerValue.timestamp() just gives me this: [".sv": "timestamp"]

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you are confused about but I know that timeStamp is a placeholder that converts into the actual value once your request makes it to server so if you are printing it out you may see the placeholder instead of value.

Answer (score 2):

hey you can try this one. working
This is extension....

```
extension Date {
func toMillis() -> Int64! {
    return Int64(self.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)
}
}
```

You can use it like

```
Date().toMillis()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly which format you have in mind: 1508805681 seems like seconds since midnight Jan 1, 1970 but timezone is unspecified. I'll assume you meant UTC.

In Firestore timestamps are stored as a [Timestamp value](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/cbe250591fca9d2e776776be065a72c5550a5556/src/google/protobuf/timestamp.proto#L121) containing seconds and a fractional part in UTC. The seconds part of that structure would get you what you want.

The Firestore SDKs expose timestamps in a way that should be natural to the host language. For example, in Swift (and Objective-C), timestamps are materialized as an `NSDate`. To get seconds since the epoch on an `NSDate`, use [`timeIntervalSince1970`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdate/1407504-timeintervalsince1970) and cast to an Int to get rid of the fractional seconds, like so:

```
Int(date.timeIntervalSince1970)
```